# How would I make a two tone gradient like this is CSS3?

Tags: css

How would I make a two tone gradient like this using only CSS3...

[image]

Comment: use this tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: This is a real question, and a valid one at that.  It's simple and straight to the point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a jsfiddle example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/PTcVt/  (tried to get approximately the same colours as you, but you may need to tweak it a bit to get it perfect)

It is done using a solid background colour, combined with a white, semi-transparent 'gradient' to overlay half of it. The 'gradient' doesn't even need to change colours; it just serves as an overlay for the solid background colour.

Like this:

.myblock {
    background-color: #0ae;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
}

The CSS3Pie site also has some good examples of what can be achieved: http://css3pie.com/demos/gradient-patterns/

(also, if you're not aware, CSS3Pie itself, from the site above, is a great little javascript hack for adding support for CSS gradients (and more) to older versions of IE)